# What does it mean for a Fresnel lens to have two finite conjugates?

Tags: optics, lenses

I'm in a situation where I need to reverse engineer a product that my company already manufactures and sells, but it wasdesigned too long ago for anyone to remember. It uses a Fresnel lens with the given specifications:

- Focal Length: 391.2mm
- Facet Spacing: 0.508mm
- Fresnel Conjugate: 6096.0mm
- Plano Conjugate: 419.0mm
- Clear Aperture: 457.2mm

What I don't understand is: what makes this double finite conjugate lens different from one with a single finite conjugate?

With a double finite conjugate Fresnel lens, you should still be able to focus collimated light to a point at the focal length, right? I just want to know why some Fresnel lenses are specified with two finite conjugates while others have infinite conjugates. Are the grooves made to accept a certain range of angles depending on the conjugate length specified?